# How can I load the transitions for a particular workflow?

Tags: 9, workflows

I want to load the transition objects for a [Workflow](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21workflows%21src%21Entity%21Workflow.php/class/Workflow/9.3.x). In Drupal 8, I see a [Workflow::getTransitions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21workflows%21src%21Entity%21Workflow.php/function/Workflow%3A%3AgetTransitions/8.3.x) method, however it seems this method was removed in Drupal 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is through the workflow's type plugin, specifically the [getTransitions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21workflows%21src%21WorkflowTypeInterface.php/function/WorkflowTypeInterface%3A%3AgetTransitions/9.1.x) method.

```
// First load a workflow, for example:
$workflow = \Drupal::service('content_moderation.moderation_information')
  ->getWorkflowForEntity($entity);

// Then get the workflow's type plugin.
/** @var \Drupal\workflows\WorkflowTypeInterface $workflow_type_plugin */
$workflow_type_plugin = $workflow->getTypePlugin();

// Finally, load the transitions.
$workflow_transitions = $workflow_type_plugin->getTransitions();
```

Alternatively, it may be more useful to only get the valid transitions for an entity, i.e. only transitions allowed for the entity from its current state, for the current user. The [getValidTransitions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_moderation%21src%21StateTransitionValidation.php/function/StateTransitionValidation%3A%3AgetValidTransitions/9.0.x) method from the [content_moderation.state_transition_validation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_moderation%21content_moderation.services.yml/service/content_moderation.state_transition_validation/9.3.x) service does this.

```
/** @var \Drupal\content_moderation\StateTransitionValidationInterface $transition_validation */
$transition_validation = \Drupal::service('content_moderation.state_transition_validation');
$valid_transitions = $transition_validation
  ->getValidTransitions($entity, \Drupal::currentUser());
```